# unable to run node js continuously on dedicated windows server

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Dedicated windows server, I am running my node express code on the server, but when an exception occurred like

```
error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    at Connection.parseE (C:\node\zykrrapi\prod\myapp\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\node\zykrrapi\prod\myapp\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:381:17)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\node\zykrrapi\prod\myapp\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:117:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:578:20)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\node\zykrrapi\prod\myapp\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:183:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\node\zykrrapi\prod\myapp\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:121:12)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:578:20)
```

and another error like "too many connections to the user on database" error also occurs and stops the execution of the code. this makes a huge loss of the data for me.

I want to run the Node Js Code continuously and to start the execution again if it stopped unexpectedly.

I am running the code using command "npm start" in windows server...

I want this node code to run only on the windows dedicated server.

Comment: theres a plugin which runs the server as a daemon, have you tried that?

Comment: From the little context you provided your errors suggests that you have some bad logic or infinity loop or unclosed connections leak.

Comment: that i can understand, i want a solution to run it even after this error occurs, if i am hosting this in HEROKU server i am not facing this issue, but my requirement is to run in windows dedicated server, so, here since this error makes the execution terminate it is not continue to execute, i am currently executing it by command " npm start " manually

Comment: how are you running the script constantly? do you have the plugin i mentioned?

Comment: i am not aware of plugins, can you  list me the plugins

Comment: you should probably use [daemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daemon) else the process will end as soon as you close the terminal